# Audio controls in Xfce 4.8

Tags: sound, configuration, xfce

I am seeing several questions similar to mine, but none of the answers are sufficient. I am pretty green with Ubuntu, so here goes:

I was just automatically upgraded to Xfce 4.8 for Ubuntu studio. The volume control no longer works in my panel. When I launch 'mixer' I don't see any settings, either.

When I try to run "Linux audio configuration" I get an error:
JACK can only be configured with a loaded and stopped studio. Please create a new studio or load and stop an existing one.

I understand that I can change the volume using command line, but I can't understand why I got upgraded to something that fails on basic features. I much less likely to recommend Ubuntu to others as a result.

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
xfce4-mixer
```

In there the "settings" are in choosing the `Sound card` and the `Controls`. If you don't do either you may indeed end up with an empty-looking up.

Does this work for you?

Answer (score 1):

I remember having a similar issue in the past. One thing I remember having to do previously is right-click on the volume indicator and you may need to select your output device. There was a change made during the 4.8 era and it switched to a different applet for volume control and I believe I ran into the same problem when that happened for me as well.